# I can't sum individual student data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my app I want to sum individual marks.

Suppose first student roll number 11 and i want to add all the marks of student roll number 11. After student roll 11 it will be student roll number 12 then 13 14 etc. In my code in i can add all marks together but separate them based on student roll number. In the below i gave a code.

Please guys help me.

Controller Code:

```
if ($this->input->post('save_exam') == "save_exam") {
    $ex_array = array();
    $exam_id = $this->input->post('exam_id');
    $student_array = $this->input->post('student');
    $exam_array = $this->input->post('exam_schedule');
    $total_marks =0;
    foreach ($student_array as $key => $student) {
        foreach ($exam_array as $key => $exam) {
            $record['get_marks'] = 0;
            $record['attendence'] = "pre";
            if ($this->input->post('student_absent' . $student . "_" . $exam) == "") {
                $get_marks = $this->input->post('student_number' . $student . "_" . $exam);
                $record['get_marks'] = $get_marks;
                $total_marks = $total_marks + $get_marks;
            } else {
                $record['attendence'] = $this->input->post('student_absent' . $student . "_" . $exam);
            }
            $record['exam_schedule_id'] = $exam;
            $record['student_id'] = $student;
            $record['exam_id'] = $this->input->post('exam_id');

            $inserted_id = $this->examresult_model->add_exam_result($record);

            if ($inserted_id) {
                $ex_array[$student] = $exam_id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample inputs, the current result of your code for those inputs, and the desired result for those inputs.

Comment: if i echo $student_array then output will be 111,112,113,114
then if i echo $total_marks then output will be sum of every number
now i want to sum all ma5ks of 111 roll number student then i want to sum all marks of 112 roll number then 113,114

Answer (score 0):

You create $total_marks as a simple variable. So, it has one value - the value for everyone. It needs to be an array. Don't set it to zero - set it to an empty array.

```
$total_marks = array();
```

As you loop through the student array, create an index in your total marks array and initialize it to zero:

```
$total_marks[$student] = 0;
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: You are reusing $key in two for loops. Bad practice!

Now, when you add to the total marks value, add it only to that one index:

```
$total_marks[$student]+= $get_marks;
```

When you are done, $total_marks will be an array, one element per student.